# Preference to many Buttons?

Tags: preferences, sharedpreferences

I ran into this problem - I have 5 Radio Button, whose number varies. There are settings that I made a Preference.
I would like to know whether you can use a Preference for each Radio Button? Ie the settings for each Radio Button should be in one Preference their possible 7 Sorry for bad English.